# What is Def.task and .taskValue in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I am reading SBT docs quite thoroughly now and there is a brief mention of `Def.task` and `taskValue` but there is no explanation so far. 
They say [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Appending-Values.html) following:

```
You can compute values of some tasks or settings to define or append a value for another task. 
It’s done by using Def.task and taskValue as an argument to :=, +=, or ++=.
```

And provide following code snippet:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  myGenerator(baseDirectory.value, (managedClasspath in Compile).value)
}.taskValue
```

This brings more questions than answers for me. How is that different from regular dependency of some SBT task on another task? When should I use this macro? etc.

I have also tried to check scaladoc but without any success really. That part of code is not documented well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this particular example in the introductory part of documentation is unnecessarily complicated. In this example you have to use `.taskValue` just because `sourceGenerators` value type is `Seq[Task[Seq[File]]]`, so you have to add a *task* to it, not the value of that task.

A simpler example for that "Tasks based on other keys’ values" is

```
homepage := Some(
  url(s"https://github.com/${organization.value}/${name.value}")
)
```

In the right part of `:=`/`+=`/`++=`/`~=` operators you can use other tasks values with simple `.value` suffix. Writing

```
foo := bar.value + 1
```

is the same as

```
foo := Def.task { bar.value + 1 }.value
```

In this simple example it's just unnecessary, but `Def.task` becomes useful when you want to separate task implementation from the *task key* setting:

```
def fooTask(n: Int): Def.Initialize[Task[Int]] = Def.task {
  bar.value + n
}
```

So `Def.task` allows you to write a task definition and use other tasks/settings inside (with `.value`). Then you can evaluate this task definition when you set the corresponding task key somewhere else (in your project settings):

```
foo := fooTask(5).value
```

But if you need to refer to the task definition itself without evaluating it, you can use `.taskValue` instead of `.value`, like in your example. See documentation on [generating sources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html) for more information about `sourceGenerators`.

Here are some other relevant parts of the sbt documentation about tasks:

- [Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html)
- [Tasks/Settings: Motivation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Task-Inputs.html)
- [Execution semantics of tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Custom-Settings.html#Execution+semantics+of+tasks)
- [Sequencing tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Sequencing.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for the roadmap :) Took some time to read that but now I understand better.